# How to add appendTo option to jQuery-UI autocomplete widget

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm working on an old project that uses the following code as a base for an autocomplete text field: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories

```
 $( function() {
    $.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
      _create: function() {
        this._super();
        this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
      },
      _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
```

I would like to add the "appendTo" option to this widget but can't work out the correct syntax from the [API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo):

> Initialize the autocomplete with the appendTo option specified:
>
> ```
> $( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
>   appendTo: "#someElem"
> });
> ```
>
> Get or set the appendTo option, after initialization:
>
> ```
> // Getter
> var appendTo = $( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "appendTo" );
>
> // Setter
> $( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "appendTo", "#someElem" );
> ```

How do I add this option to a jQuery UI autocomplete widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seemed to miss the end of the example source script (in your documentation link).  It activates the autocomplete with:

```
$( "#search" ).catcomplete({
  delay: 0,
  source: data
});
```

To use the appendTo, then is as simple as:

```
$( "#search" ).catcomplete({
  delay: 0,
  source: data,
  appendTo: '#someElem'
});
```

where you are appending to a selection `$('#someElem')`